# How would the Xpath of this "text" look like?

Tags: selenium, xpath

So, I am trying to edit the text of an element but I do not know why I can't.

This is basically what I am trying to edit: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7B82.png)
Sorry cannot embed yet

I have tried `//*[@id=':so']/text()` but it does not seem to work.

I am using Selenium IDE to capture. However, it does not capture me editing the text on the webpage, hence, not getting any xpath in the IDE.

I am trying to edit the reply-to text in Gmail.

Sorry for my bad English....

Comment: You are using Selenium IDE, try using Selenium webdriver.

Comment: @YuZhang Even with using webdriver it does not work. I am using Java.

Comment: @AAlzaabi try by this xpath `//*[@id=':so']`...and after getting element you should call `.getText()` for getting text....selenium `webdriver` does not find only text element....

Comment: @SaurabhGaur But I am trying to use `.sendKeys()`

Comment: Ah...@AAlzaabi means you want to set value in the div??

Comment: @SaurabhGaur Yes, I want to set the value to anything I want. However, nothing I do in selenium IDE or webdriver changes it. The only thing that changes it is if I go and type physically in the body area.

Comment: Then you need yo use `JavaScriptExectuor` to set value in div...let give you the answer..

Comment: @SaurabhGaur Could you please explain more on how would the command look like? I am only experienced in Java.

Comment: @AAlzaabi..Yeah please see the answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set value in `div` using `JavaScriptExectuor` as below :-

```
WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id=':so']"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].textContent = arguments[1]", el, "value to set");
```

Hope it will help you..:)

Comment: OMG!!! It finally worked. Thank you very much!! I have been trying everyday for a week!!! Thank you!!!!!!